# Twitter API: Get latest Tweets for an keyword including GEO - Cords?

Tags: api, twitter

Is there any way to get the Cords of the "Twitterer" when using Twitter Search Api? If i understand the API Doc right, is there no GEO Result in their XML / JSON return object?

Comment: got it, there are nearly no tweets with geo cords added (-:

Answer (score 0):

You can get tweets against coordinates by using following code

```
var search = FluentTwitter.CreateRequest().Search().Query()
    .Within(searchMiles).Of(geoLocation).AsJson();
```